# Are there any alternatives to using OpenCV's imdecode? It is too slow

Tags: c++, image, opencv, memory-management

I have created a DLL where the user can either read an image from a file name or from a stream as follows:

```
std::string filePath = "SomeImage.bmp";

// (1) Reading from a file
Image2D img1;
img1.readImage(filePath);

// (2) Reading from a stream
std::ifstream imgStream (filePath.c_str(), std::ios::binary);
Image2D img2;
img2.readImage(imgStream);
```

The first `readImage(filePath)` is implemented using `cv::imread(filePath)` which is reasonably fast (on average 0.001 seconds for a 600 x 900 image). However, the second version `readImage(fileStream)` is implemented using `cv::imdecode` which is **considerably slower** (on average 2.5 seconds for the same image).

Are there any alternatives to `cv::imdecode` where I can decode an image from a memory buffer without taking such a long time? This is for the core component of an application that is frequently used, so it has to be quick.

Any assistance would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I measure the timings using a timer. It didn't make sense to me too. I don't understand why there is such a large disparity in the time. `Image2D` is just a class that has an OpenCV matrix as a member. The implementation of the `readImage` functions are simplified as follows:

```
int Image2D::readImage(std::ifstream& input)
{       
    input.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    size_t fileSize = input.tellg();
    input.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

    if (fileSize == 0) {
        return 1;
    }

    std::vector<unsigned char> data(fileSize);
    input.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&data[0]), sizeof(unsigned char) * fileSize);

    if (!input) {
        return 1;
    }

    StopWatch stopWatch;
    mImg = cv::imdecode(cv::Mat(data), CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    std::cout << "Time to decode: " << stopWatch.getElapsedTime() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}


int Image2D::readImage(const std::string& fileName)
{
    StopWatch stopWatch;
    mImg = cv::imread(fileName, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

    std::cout << "Time to read image: " << stopWatch.getElapsedTime() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do you measure the timings? This doesn't seem to make much sense: `imread` uses `imdecode` internally, and you are just reading a bitmap file which actually has no decoding at all. You should also show the code for your class `Image2D` and the method `readImage` implementation (the 2 overloaded options).

Comment: how's that stopwatch implemented? since you first measure imread, maybe its some kind of singleton and not resetted?

Comment: measuring with clock (I know it's cpu time, not wall time), the stream version is a little faster (but it's just the decoding) on my system.

Comment: @Micka No, it's definitely not a Singleton. Just a simple lightweight class using Windows _ftime64_s. I don't understand how the stream version is faster on your machine but considerably slower on mine. In fact, on a couple of machines I tested it on, it was slower.

Comment: @Duncs are you 100% certain that it's not a bug in your time measurement? Did you try to perform the stream-decode method before the imread method? And btw, what's your image size?

Answer (score 2):

This is how I tested your code, maybe you can try the same (in a clean project) to compare results.

For me, time measurement (CPU time, it's not wall time) says it's a bit faster to just decode the byte stream than to imread the image (which makes sense) - Windows - VC 2010 OpenCV 2.49

```
#include <fstream>

cv::Mat MreadImage(std::ifstream& input)
{       
    input.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    size_t fileSize = input.tellg();
    input.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

    if (fileSize == 0) {
        return cv::Mat();
    }

    std::vector<unsigned char> data(fileSize);
    input.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&data[0]), sizeof(unsigned char) * fileSize);

    if (!input) {
        return cv::Mat();
    }

    clock_t startTime = clock();
    cv::Mat mImg = cv::imdecode(cv::Mat(data), CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    clock_t endTime = clock();
    std::cout << "Time to decode image: " << (float)(endTime-startTime)/(float)CLOCKS_PER_SEC << std::endl;

    return mImg;
}


cv::Mat MreadImage(const std::string& fileName)
{
    clock_t startTime = clock();
    cv::Mat mImg = cv::imread(fileName, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    clock_t endTime = clock();

    std::cout << "Time to read image: " << (float)(endTime-startTime)/(float)CLOCKS_PER_SEC << std::endl;
    return mImg;
}

// test speed of imread vs imdecode
int main()
{

    //std::string path = "../inputData/Lenna.png";
    //std::string path = "../inputData/Aachen_Germany_Imperial-Cathedral-01.jpg";
    std::string path = "../inputData/bmp.bmp";

    cv::Mat i1 = MreadImage(path);


    std::ifstream imgStream (path.c_str(), std::ios::binary);
    cv::Mat i2 = MreadImage(imgStream);

    cv::imshow("input 1", i1);
    cv::imshow("input 2", i2);
    cv::waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So I tested the above code in a clean project and the times are about the same as you mentioned. I really do not understand why it takes longer to just run `imdecode` in my production level application. I would have to dig into this a little deeper. I may be missing something. Any advice would help. Thanks.

Comment: did you try the alternative time measurement method in your production code?

Comment: Yes, I did. I don't understand why it takes so long. I created a work-around for this issue but I am still bewildered by the differences in time. I have no clue why it takes a longer time when I explicitly call `cv::imdecode`. Thanks for your help though.